# Checking if there is an animation going on in jQuery

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm using jQuery. I defined an existing boolean called 'animating', that should tell me wether jQuery is doing an animation with animation(). I've got quite a few animations, implementing this in every animation declaration would be quite alot of work, and messy.

So my question is, is there a way to tell jQuery, whenever the function animation() is called, it does its usual thing but also sets animating = true, and when it's done, animating = false. Or is there a better way?

Comment: You should take a look at .queue() - http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know if it is animating in general ?

If you care for specific elements you can query them with `.is(':animated')`.

You could even use it in general with

```
if ($(':animated').length) {
  // something is being animated
} else {
  // nothing is being animated
}
```

but that might be overkill..

Look for the [`:animated` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Comment: I'm checking if anything is animating because my script should only allow one animation happen on the same time. Would there be a better way to do this?